# Can anyone explain this code related to shadowing in Java?

Tags: java, shadowing

While going through Oracle docs reading about Nested classes, I found this piece of code whose output I could not understand. Can someone please explain this ?

```
public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

The following is the output of this example:

```
x = 23
this.x = 1
ShadowTest.this.x = 0 //why is 0 printed here? why not 1 because "this" is the object of FirstLevel class.
```

The original code can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? Please explain more.

Comment: what is the problem - dont you understand all outputs, just one ?

Comment: Prefixing `this` with the name of an enclosing class, such as `ShadowTest.this.x`, causes it to refer to the enclosing object.

Comment: I did not understand the output of  ShadowTest.this.x .

Comment: @RishabhGour - See the `field` that will be used depends on the reference using which it is called. `ShadowTest.this.x` means accessing `ShadowTest's` `x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local variable `x` shadows `this.x` and `ShadowTest.this.x`.

The instance variable of the inner class (`this.x`) shadows the instance variable of the enclosing class (which can be accessed by `ShadowTest.this.x`).

```
System.out.println("x = " + x); // prints the local variable passed to the method
System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x); // prints the instance variable of the inner class
System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x); // prints the instance variable of the enclosing class instance
```

Comment: Sir, what does ShadowTest.this actually means ? In my understanding this should refer to object of FirstLevel class and ShadowTest.this should mean accessing a member of ShadowTest,"this".

Comment: @RishabhGour `ShadowTest.this` refers to the enclosing instance of your inner class instance (i.e. the instance of `ShadowTest` associated with the instance of `FirstLevel` for which the method was called).

Comment: so if suppose there is a class C inside a class B which is inside a class A then I can refer to class A object from within class C by saying A.this and same applies for class B also, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this wasn't fully explained beyond the documentation found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) so I am going to try to go into more detail based on my recent understanding.

I've changed the name of the `ShadowClass` outer class to `NestedClasses` and changed the variables from type `int` to type `String`.

Here is an example of adding a second nested class within the first nested class to show how `NestedClasses.this.x` continues to behave in deeper layers of classes.

```
public class NestedClasses {
    
    public String x = "outer class variable";
    
    class FirstLevel {

        public String x = "first level class variable";

        void methodInFirstLevel(String x) {
            System.out.println("methodInFirstLevel:");
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("NestedClasses.this.x = " + NestedClasses.this.x);
        }
        
        class SecondLevel {
            
            public String x = "second level class variable";

            void methodInSecondLevel(String x) {
                System.out.println("methodInSecondLevel:");
                System.out.println("x = " + x);
                System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
                System.out.println("NestedClasses.this.x = " + NestedClasses.this.x);
                System.out.println("FirstLevel.this.x = " + FirstLevel.this.x);
                System.out.println("NestedClasses.FirstLevel.this.x = " + NestedClasses.FirstLevel.this.x);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NestedClasses st = new NestedClasses();
        NestedClasses.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        NestedClasses.FirstLevel.SecondLevel sl = fl.new SecondLevel();

        fl.methodInFirstLevel("first level method arg");
        System.out.println();
        sl.methodInSecondLevel("second level method arg");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

methodInFirstLevel:
`x` = first level method arg
`this.x` = first level class variable 
`NestedClasses.this.x` = outer class variable

methodInSecondLevel:
`x` = second level method arg
`this.x` = second level class variable
`NestedClasses.this.x` = outer class variable
`FirstLevel.this.x` = first level class variable
 `NestedClasses.FirstLevel.this.x` = first level class variable

Each of the three instantiated objects (`st`, `fl`, `sl`) contain a pointer to different *memory space* in the heap where the value of `x` can be found. I believe the compiler is searching "backwards" towards the outermost layer to find the first matching class when it see's a class name prefixed to `this` in a nested class. The first matching class it finds is the class it will refer to when determining which object instantiation it needs to search to find `x`. This would mean `NestedClasses.FirstLevel.this.x` is really taking two steps backward and one step forward to determine which *memory space* to look at in the heap, i.e. which memory space `x` references.

**Summery:**
`NestedClasses.this.x`

- The prefixed Class Name `NestedClasses` tells the JVM which class is being used, this class must be reachable from the current scope.
- The `this` keyword tells the JVM to look at the *memory space* of an instantiated object of the class being referred to, rather than the *memory space* of the class object itself (which is used for static members of the class). More specifically, `this` will reference the instantiation of the outer class that was used (and required) to instantiate the non-static inner class.
- the object member `x` appended to `this` tells the JVM what to search for in the *memory space* it is looking at.